# How do I change the timestamp for each new input taken?

Tags: python, python-3.9

So I'm trying to make a program where the user inputs notes and it timestamps them, but when I run this all the date-times are the same. Is there any way I can change this?

```
from time import time, ctime
t = time()
noteno = int(input("How many notes would you like to add? "))
for i in range (noteno):
 note = input("Add note: ")
 stamp1 = ctime(t)
 print(f"Note stamped at: {stamp1}")
```

Comment: Include `t = time()` in your loop - you only read it once before entering it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the t=time() in for loop.

```
from time import time, ctime
noteno = int(input("How many notes would you like to add? "))
for i in range (noteno):
    t = time()
    note = input("Add note: ")
    stamp1 = ctime(t)
    print(f"Note stamped at: {stamp1}")
```